# React, avoid rerendering with shallowEqual

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to see performance problems and trying to optimize it.

As a first step, I'm dealing with `Perf.printWasted()`

That is I'm trying to eliminate unnecessary renders.

One of my component is being rerendered because of two props

1. a `new` date object.
2. newly created `[todo]` array

Suppose you are creating a calendar for todo.
For each date, I'm passing a date, and list of todos which are due that day.
I'm doing something like (simplified)

```
todoForDay = _.filter(todos, (todo) => {return todo.dueDate == today})
```

react's shallowEqual wouldn't see those two cases as equal, how should I proceed?

For #1, I could think of passing `moment(date).format()` as props and converting back to date object every time I pass the date.
But it would get really tiresome, because there are so many child components that needs access to the date.

Comment: I found this article to be extremely helpful when I was trying to optimize React performance: https://blog.vixlet.com/react-at-light-speed-78cd172a6411?gi=21352787ca77#.beaiosjbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing my solutions.

For calendar based todo list, I wanted to avoid implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` for every subcomponents for a calendar day.

So I looked for a way to cache the dates I created for the calendar. (Unless you change the month, you see the same range of dates) .

So https://github.com/reactjs/reselect was a great fit.

I solved #2 with the reselect as well.

It memoizes (caches) function result until function params change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method? You could check for the inequality of the passed in date prop and todos array like so:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { 
      date,
      todos,
    } = this.props;
    const {
      date: prevDate,
      todos: prevTodos,
    } = prevProps;

    return (
      date.getTime() !== prevDate.getTime() ||
      !_.isEqual(todos, prevTodos)
    );
  }

  render() {
    // render...
  }
}
```

The `_.isEqual` method performs a deep equality comparison of the two `todos` arrays. There is also a `_.isEqualWith` method you could use to define your own notion of equality for those arrays if you want to be more specific.

Alternatively, you could look into something like Immutable.js as it would allow you to do an easier `todos !== prevTodos` comparison, but this might be overkill for your needs (depending on how much data you're working with).

If you're already doing something like this, perhaps provide some more code (your implemented `shouldComponentUpdate` method so we can suggest other alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

For #1 you don't need to convert the prop. You can simply compare the dates with `getTime()` in `shouldComponentUpdate()`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return this.props.date.getTime() !== nextProps.date.getTime()
}
```

And for #2 unfortunately it looks like an array which contains objects, I think doing a deep equal here is more expensive than just a render.

Note that executing `render()` doesn't mean that the DOM will get an update. If you setup `key` properly then it should be fast enough. (If the todos may change its order or the newly added todo is added on top then don't use indexes as the key. Real unique keys are better in that case)

You should try to avoid unnecessary `setState` (if you are not using a state management library). Also try to split your components to small pieces. Instead of re-rendering a huge component every time it has an update, updating only the minimum sections of your app should be faster.

Another possibility is to re-structure your state. But it's based on your requirements. If you don't need the full datetime of each todo, you can group your state something like:

```
todos: {
  '2017-04-28': ['Watch movie', 'Jogging'],
  '2017-04-29': ['Buy milk']
}
```

By doing this you don't even need the filter. You can grab the todos of the date your want easily.

In a more complex case which you need more information, you can try to normalize your state, for example:

```
{
  todos: {
    1: { text: 'Watch movie', completed: true, addedTime: 1493476371925 },
    2: { text: 'Jogging', completed: true, addedTime: xxxxxxxxxx},
    3: { text: 'Buy milk', completed: false, addedTime: xxxxxxxxxx}
  },
  byDate: {
    '2017-04-28': [1, 2],
    '2017-04-29': [3]
  }
}
```

Now if add a new todo to the `todos`, it won't affect your component which is referring to `byDate` so you can make sure that there is no unnecessary re-renders.